# How to Create a Custom Salesforce Login Page in a HTML/Javscript Phonegap Mobile App

Tags: soap, phonegap

I am developing a salesforce mobile app using HTML5 and Javascript. I want to create a customized login page with their own brand and message to ask user to input username and password(without security token). Then our apps can access any resource of salesforce like call a custom service to fetch data or upload data.

I know we can use OAuth2.0 to do the thing of login, but we can not change the login page? We can only use salesforce standard login page?

How to build this customized login page in  HTML5 and Javascript Phonegap mobile App? Soap service?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using Oauth flow as it is super secure .

Salesforce also provides option that you can put your own logo in login screens

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_login_branding.htm&language=en_US

But then if you are looking for other options there is one from Brian below in his github

http://brianpeddle.com/2011/06/06/building-a-custom-salesforce-login/

Comment: I check this links, but I still get my answer. I need build a mobile login page, then I can input username and password to call salesforce web service from mobile app.